# TikZ: Why does moving anchor= to a style change the result?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-node

Here is code which renders as expected. I want to refactor it.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt,a4paper]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,intersections,shapes,backgrounds,scopes,positioning,fit,matrix}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{varname/.style={rectangle,thin,inner sep=0.3ex,font=\ttfamily,text height=1.5ex,text depth=0.35ex}}
\tikzset{vartype/.style={rectangle,text=red,thin,inner sep=0.3ex,font=\ttfamily,text height=1.5ex,text depth=0.35ex}}
\tikzset{struct/.style={draw,matrix of nodes,column 1/.style={anchor=base west},column 2/.style={anchor=base west}}}
\tikzset{structtype/.style={rectangle,draw,text=red,fill=white,thin,inner sep=0.3ex,font=\ttfamily,text height=1.5ex,text depth=0.35ex}}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (foo) [struct]
{
    \node[varname] (age) {age}; & \node[vartype] {int*};  & \\
    \node[varname] {height};    & \node[vartype] {float}; & \\
    \node[varname] {weight};    & \node[vartype] {float}; & \\
};
\node[structtype,above=2ex of age.west,anchor=west]  {Foo};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Every `structtype` node will be anchored in the same way to the corresponding matrix, so I want to move the `2ex` and `anchor=west` parts into a style so I would only have to write something like this each time:

```
\node[structtype,above=of FOO.west]  {...};
```

instead of

```
\node[structtype,above=2ex of FOO.west,anchor=west]  {...};
```

My attempt to move `anchor=west` to the style gives a different rendering:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt,a4paper]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,intersections,shapes,backgrounds,scopes,positioning,fit,matrix}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{varname/.style={rectangle,thin,inner sep=0.3ex,font=\ttfamily,text height=1.5ex,text depth=0.35ex}}
\tikzset{vartype/.style={rectangle,text=red,thin,inner sep=0.3ex,font=\ttfamily,text height=1.5ex,text depth=0.35ex}}
\tikzset{struct/.style={draw,matrix of nodes,column 1/.style={anchor=base west},column 2/.style={anchor=base west}}}
\tikzset{structtype/.style={rectangle,draw,text=red,fill=white,thin,inner sep=0.3ex,font=\ttfamily,text height=1.5ex,text depth=0.35ex,anchor=west}}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (foo) [struct]
{
    \node[varname] (age) {age}; & \node[vartype] {int*};  & \\
    \node[varname] {height};    & \node[vartype] {float}; & \\
    \node[varname] {weight};    & \node[vartype] {float}; & \\
};
\node[structtype,above=2ex of age.west]  {Foo};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

How do I refactor "put it this much above whatever other thing, anchored west" into a style?

Comment: because `above right` override `anchor` option. When you use both, always option `anchor=...` should be the last between options.

Comment: An alternative: `\node[structtype, right= 0pt of foo.north-|age.west] {Foo};`

Comment: @TorbjørnT., done! Thank you to encourage me. However, now I'm not sure, if I correctly understand OP problem. Anyway, I significantly rewrote his MWE. See below:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose, that you like to obtain the following result:

[image]

I (significantly) rewrote your code, hopefully on desired way and that the code is self explanatory:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, 
                backgrounds, 
                fit,
                intersections,
                matrix,
                positioning,
                scopes, 
                shapes}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\tikzset{Matrix/.style ={% named as Matrix, moved in preamble, 
varname/.style = {% now serve also as common nodes style
                  rectangle, inner sep=0.3ex,
                  text height=1.5ex, text depth=0.35ex,
                  font=\ttfamily},
vartype/.style = {varname, text=red},         % simplified
 struct/.style = {matrix of nodes,
                  draw, outer sep=0pt,
                  nodes={anchor=base west},   % added
                  column 1/.style={varname},  % changed
                  column 2/.style={vartype}}, % changed
structtype/.style={vartype, draw, fill=white, 
                   above=-0.35ex}             % changed
                            }
        }% end of tikzset

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[Matrix]% Matrix indicate name of used tikzset 
\matrix (M) [struct]
{
    age     &   int*    \\      % simplified
    height  &   float   \\      % simplified
    weight  &   float   \\      % simplified
};
\node[structtype]  at (M-1-1.north) {Foo};% changed as I understood you wish to have
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

*Note:* When you use `above right` and `anchor` option and you like that`anchor` is considered, it should be the last between options. In contrary case `above right` will overwrite `anchor` option.

**Edit:** An alternative simple solution is:

- define `structtype` as `structtype/.style={vartype, draw, fill=white}`
- positioning node with content "Foo" as `\node[structtype]  at (M-1-1 |- M.north) {Foo};`

Result will be the same as before.